# Discord Bot doesnt respond to Commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

My Discord Bot doesnt respond to Commands, but it logs the User ID when someone writes something. Why is this the Case? What have i done wrong? Is there something missing in the on_message listener? The last thing i added to my Code was the Rank System which i am working on, but even when i comment it out, the Bot still doesnt respond to commands like +macarena. Here is the Code:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from user import User

############## Init Variables #############

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')
DATA = os.getcwd() + '\\data\\'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')
bot.remove_command('help')

rank_list = []

############## Main Code #############
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{bot.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

    if(os.path.isfile(DATA + 'database.txt')):
        print('Database File for Rank System exists and is ready for processing!')
    else:
        print('Database File doesnt exist and will be created....')
        create_file()
        print('File is created and ready for use!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    #rank_system(message)
    pass


@bot.command(name='help')
async def help_command(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Bot Commands",
        description = "Hier werden alle Commands von diesem Bot aufgelistet. Alle nachfolgenden Commands müssen mit dem Präfix '+' aufgerufen werden.",
        color = discord.Color.blue()
    )
    embed.add_field(name="Algorithmen", value="Lexikon", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Datenstrukturen", value="Lexikon", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="macarena", value="Fun Commands", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

#Rank System
def rank_system(message):
    author = str(message.author)
    userid = str(message.author.id) 
    time = str(message.created_at)
    channel = str(message.channel)

    user = search_user(userid)
    if user == None:
        rank_list.append(User(author,userid,time,channel))
    else:
        user.add_xp()
    print(userid)

@bot.command(name='rank')
async def get_rank(message):
    print("I am Here")
    id = str(message.author.id)
    user = search_user(id)
    response = f"You are Rank {user.get_rank()} and you have {user.get_xp()}."
    await message.channel.send(response)
    

#Lexikon Commands
@bot.command(name='Algorithmen')
async def algo_command(message):
    response = "Es gibt viele verschiedene Algorithmen hier eine kurze Auflistung von den bekanntesten:\n\n- Bubble Sort\n- Quick Sort\n- Merge Sort"
    await message.channel.send(response)

@bot.command(name='Datenstrukturen')
async def datenstrukturen_command(message):
    response = "Es gibt viele verschiedene Datenstrukturen hier eine kurze Auflistung von den bekanntesten:\n\n- Stack\n- Queue\n- List"
    await message.channel.send(response)

#Vote Commands


#Fun Commands
@bot.command(name='macarena')
async def makarena_command(message):
    print("Funktioniert")
    response = "Hast du ernsthaft so viel Langeweile, dass du diesen Command ausprobierst....Schäm dich ;)"
    await message.channel.send(response)

#Sound Board


#Helper Class
def create_file():
    open(os.path.join(DATA, "database.txt"), "x")

def read_file():
    pass

def write_file(text):
    pass

def search_user(id):
    for x in rank_list:
        print("Loop User %s",x.get_userID())
        if x.get_userID() == id:
            return x
    return None


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Thanks for the Help in advance :) I am really confused and cant figure out what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `process_commands()` at the end of `on_message` events to make other commands work. [Read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    #some code if you want, if you want to pass then don't make on_message event
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and change your command names like this

```py
@bot.command()
async def macarena(message):
   #code
```

It will run when using `{prefix}macarena`

Comment: Changed it, but there is still no response from the Bot